# How to make tcl glob command accept wild card in -directory or run find command on the same to get the results?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to write a tcl script which would find files of specific extension under some specific patterns of directory. Part of the full path of the directory in which I want to find will be dynamic hence I need to use '*' to pattern it out.

However, I am getting error while using '*' in both the glob and exec find for the directory as tcl says it can't find such directory.

With glob:

```
set find_dir "/home/user/output/*/logs/" 
if {[llength [set log_files [glob -nocomplain -directory $find_dir *.log]]]} {
  foreach log_file $log_files {
    puts $log_file
  }
}
```

With find :

```
set find_dir "/home/user/output/*/logs/" 
set log_files [exec find $find_dir -name *.log]
foreach log_file $log_files {
  puts $log_file
}
```

How can I achieve this in tcl with the constraint the directory I want to find into will have '*' in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-directory` argument doesn't accept a pattern, by design. Only the main pattern arguments accept patterns. However, the main pattern arguments *do* handle directory separators.

You need something like this:

```
set find_dir "/home/user/output" 
if {[llength [set log_files [glob -nocomplain -directory $find_dir */logs/*.log]]]} {
  foreach log_file $log_files {
    puts $log_file
  }
}
```

Comment: It works & serves my purpose that I want to narrow down the search into a specific directory to avoid searching from a top level directory on all that is underneath. Just wondering if this would have the same effect. Thanks much.

Comment: Originally (back a few decades ago) there were no `-directory` or `-path` arguments, and everything had to go in the pattern. Which caused various problems because of interference with glob metacharacters (all on Unix, backslash only on Windows but very frequently there). So those options were added (to each address a slightly different use case). I don't care for `-path` myself, but `-directory` suits me nicely.